# using other method than innerHTML in js?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Redigeringsbara stycken</h1>
    <p class="editable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>
```

//JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload = function  () {
    /*
    var pElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i=0; i < pElements.length; i++) {
        if(pElements[i].className == 'editable')
            inPlaceEditor(pElements[i]);
    };
    */
   document.onclick = catchIt;
};

function inPlaceEditor (editableElement) {

}

var editing = false;

if (document.getElementById && document.createElement)
{
   var butt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var buttext = document.createTextNode('Ready!');
    butt.appendChild(buttext);
    butt.onclick = saveEdit;
}

function catchIt(e) {
    if (editing) {
          alert("U're still editing!!");
        return;
    }
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement) return;
    if (!e) var obj = window.event.srcElement;
    else var obj = e.target;
    while (obj.nodeType != 1) {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
        alert(obj.nodeType);
    }
    if (obj.tagName == 'textarea' || obj.tagName == 'a') return;
    while (obj.nodeName != 'P' && obj.nodeName != 'HTML')
    {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
        alert(obj.nodeName);
    }
    if (obj.nodeName == 'HTML') {
        // alert ("this is HTML");
        return;
    }
    //other way to grab the text instead of innerHTML-method????
    var targetInnerHtml = obj.innerHTML;
    var textArea= document.createElement('textarea');
    var parentnode = obj.parentNode;
    parentnode.insertBefore(textArea, obj);
    parentnode.insertBefore("<br />", obj);
    parentnode.insertBefore(butt, obj);
    parentnode.removeChild(obj);
    textArea.value = targetInnerHtml ;
    textArea.focus();
    editing = true;
}

function saveEdit() {
    var area = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    var paragraph = document.createElement('P');
    var parentnode = area.parentNode;
    paragraph.innerHTML = area.value;
    parentnode.insertBefore(paragraph, area);
    parentnode.removeChild(area);
    parentnode.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]);
    editing = false;
}
```

HELLO GULRS AND BOYS! Im wondering if: 1- there's another way to grab the html-text instead of using innerHtml- method? for those who work in Jquery would it be easier to implement this code in Jquery? lest lines, faster maybe? gracias! :)

Comment: You may know about this already and dislike its lack of functionality for adding new elements or editing attributes and whatnot, but `contenteditable="true"` will make the text content of a node and its child elements editable by the user. This works for me in Chrome, FF and IE8. [See here for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/JxyGB/)

Comment: @Bryan hi there! CAnt follow u! u didnt write any code in yr example?

Comment: @Bryan what do u mean? u didn't write any code in yr example? what is this contenteditable="true?

Comment: Click the link ("See here for an example") at the end of my comment or follow this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JxyGB/
In any case, if you want an entire `div` to be editable, you would write `<div contenteditable="true">`. Note that the specifics of its implementation vary from browser to browser, but the basics are fairly good cross-browser. It's actually been around since IE5.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it simple if you can use jQuery. What is the event used by you?

You can use the [jQuery html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to get/set the innerHTML.

To get innerHTML

```
$(obj).html()
```

To set it:

```
$(textArea).value(targetInnerHtml)
```

Comment: Can u tell us what exactly u r looking for? What I understood is if you click on an `p` or `html` element then you are creating a textarea and adding the content of the clicked element to the text area, is it correct?

Comment: it's very correct! I want to edit the text that I click on..basically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just want the text, so you can write:

```
var targetText = obj.textContent || obj.innerText;
```

A more robust version is:

```
if (typeof obj.textContent == 'string') {
    targetText = obj.textContent;
} else if (typeof obj.innerText == 'string') {
    targetText = obj.innerText;
}
```

Which can be turned into a function so you can call it rather than having to write the above each time.

Other comments:

```
function catchIt(e) {
editing = false;

  if (editing) {
```

How will *editing* ever be true?

```
  parentnode.insertBefore(butt, obj);
```

*butt* is not declared or initialised anywhere.

Comment: editing is true at the end of the catchIt function...as long as u are inside editing the text is true...are u follwing me?

Comment: @YoniGeek I believe Rob was saying that the original `if (editing) {...}` statement doesn't do anything, because you declare `editing` will be false right before it. Maybe it makes sense in other functions, but here the `if` statement will never evaluate under any circumstance.

Comment: @Bryan if I may Bryan: It's not actually true.If u taste the code I wrote an alert to prove this behavior...click on the text than try to click somewhere else, u'll not be able to do anything than the editing....in this way I check if the user is still editing the text.  are u following me? :)